# Lock Service Appointments in Gantt (Field Service)

Tags: field-service-lightning, fieldservice

does anybody know if there is some possibility (e.g. permission set) to lock the gantt diagram in the FS for a specific user? There is this possibility to lock/unlock the whole gantt but the problem is that the user can do it on its own and unlock it if he likes. 
I haven't found any permission for this yet. The goal is that some users should not be able to reschedule the service appointments with drag and drop inside the gantt

[image]